# Binding menu item IsChecked to a setting

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is not working right:

```
<MenuItem x:Uid="MenuItem_12" Header="400%" IsCheckable="True"
          IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static Properties:Settings.Default}, Path=ZoomFactor, Converter={StaticResource IsValidZoomFactor}, ConverterParameter='400'}"/>
```

In my `Settings` I have a integer `ZoomFactor`. The settings are set to **Public** and scope **User**.

At the top of my XAML I have a namespace:

```
xmlns:Properties="clr-namespace:OCLMEditor.Properties"
```

And this is my `ValueConverter`:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace OCLMEditor.ValueConverters
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(bool))]
    public class IsCurrentZoomFactor : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int desiredZoomFactor = (int)value;
            int currentZoomFactor = (int)parameter;

            return desiredZoomFactor == currentZoomFactor;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

But I get an error:

> 1>D:\My Programs\OCLMEditor\OCLMEditor\MainWindow.xaml(143,35): error MC3044: The text '}' is not allowed after the closing '}' of a MarkupExtension expression. Line 143 Position 35.

I have several other menu items too:

```
<MenuItem x:Uid="MenuItem_13" Header="300%" IsCheckable="True"/>
<MenuItem x:Uid="MenuItem_14" Header="250%" IsCheckable="True"/>
<MenuItem x:Uid="MenuItem_15" Header="200%" IsCheckable="True"/>
<MenuItem x:Uid="MenuItem_16" Header="175%" IsCheckable="True"/>
<MenuItem x:Uid="MenuItem_17" Header="150%" IsCheckable="True"/>
<MenuItem x:Uid="MenuItem_18" Header="125%" IsCheckable="True"/>
```

I am not sure I am going about this the right way but the idea is:

1. Pass the Settings.ZoomFactor value to the converter.
2. Pass the expected zoom factor value to the converter.
3. Compare them both and if they are the same, set it as checked.

In addition, at the moment it is "changed" so another zoom factor, the setting to be updated. I assumed that binding to the "setting" was the right way to go. But have errors.

I confirm that the error is on the `IsChecked` line:

[image: Editor]

Updated error:

[image: Error]

This bit on its own has no visual errors:

```
<MenuItem x:Uid="MenuItem_12" Header="400%" IsCheckable="True"
          IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static Properties:Settings.Default}, Path=ZoomFactor}"/>
```

So it is the introduction of the converter / value that it goes wrong.

For now, I had to change my converter:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace OCLMEditor.ValueConverters
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(bool))]
    public class IsCurrentZoomFactor : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int currentZoomFactor = (int)value;
            string strDesiredZoomFactor = (string)parameter;
            int desiredZoomFactor = int.Parse(strDesiredZoomFactor);
            return desiredZoomFactor == currentZoomFactor;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Because we are passing '400' it is a string. So I have to cast it to integer. If I remove the '  ' it will not accept passing it as an integer.

Comment: Are you certain that MenuItem is what's on line 143/position 35? That error indicates an orphaned closing curly brace in a binding or whatever: `Foo="{Binding Bar}}"` for example

Comment: @EdPlunkett The braces apprear to be correct.

Comment: They do appear correct. It's not the single quotes, they were fine where you had them. Nothing else is on that line, right? Did you clean the solution, restart VS, and build? That's always worth trying when the XAML editor seems to be losing its mind.

Comment: @EdPlunkett No joy I am afraid. The setting is a integer, the parameter I want to pass is an integer. The return value should be a bool.

Comment: Did the new version of the converter solve the problem?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Partly. If I manually change the settings in the application resources it will correctly tick the right one. But as soon as I go to tick another menu item, it hits the `ConvertBack` and because it is not implemented it fails. I have some confusion over the parameters the `ConvertBack` is being sent. Is this considered a separate question?

Comment: Ah, OK. I'd just comment out the `throw` in the ConvertBack method, or else set `Mode=OneWay` on the `Binding`. I don't think you want to be driving changes back to the source through that binding.

Comment: @EdPlunkett OK. Feel free to comment on my answer. The next step is to actually perform an action in my application with a command. And at that point I suppose it could update the setting, as opposed to the menu. So you are suggesting I leave it set to mode one way and perhaps use code behind for a click action? Since I have to convert the webbrowser control to get to the webbrowser2 control to call execwb to fire the zoom change you see.

Comment: I don't think there's any "back conversion" there. You have a command or something that sets the zoom factor, and when the zoom factor changes, the menu items check or uncheck themselves. Nothing is going in the other direction. You could do a command, or just a click event they all share, set the `Tag` property of each MenuItem to the appropriate zoom factor; in the click handler, `Settings.Default.ZoomFactor = Int32.Parse((String) ((MenuItem)sender).Tag);` Not pure MVVM but you don't always have to be a fanatic about these things.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I will have a go with your answer. See how I get on. Thanks.

Comment: Added a update at the end of my answer below -- it's not a zoom factor converter, it's really a generally useful integer equality check converter.

Comment: Wasn't it @Fruchtzwerg who actually answered the question?

Comment: @EdPlunkett His answer still had errors. Removing the quotes was not enough. Unless I missed something. Besides, he completely changed his answer and it does not seem he told me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the trouble here was related to the fact that `Binding.ConverterParameter` is a string, because the XAML parser has no way of knowing what type is expected.

Here's a way to rewrite your value converter with a strongly typed parameter (or multiple parameters, if you like). It's always a win if you can move parameter type checking from a runtime error in your code to a design time message in the IDE.

```
public class IsCurrentZoomFactor : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public int DesiredZoomFactor { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int currentZoomFactor = (int)value;
        return DesiredZoomFactor == currentZoomFactor;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And use it like this. Note that we aren't creating an instance of `IsCurrentZoomFactor` as a resource. Since it's a `MarkupExtension`, we instantiate it right where we use it, and we initialize its parameter property right there as well. The advantage of this is that the XAML parser knows `DesiredZoomFactor` is an integer.

You'd use it like this:

```
<MenuItem 
    x:Uid="MenuItem_12" Header="400%" IsCheckable="True"
    IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static Properties:Settings.Default}, Path=ZoomFactor, Converter={local:IsCurrentZoomFactor DesiredZoomFactor=400}}"
    />
```

This is very handy because it makes value converters self-documenting. When you type `{local:IsCurrentZoomFactor` in the XAML, the XAML editor gives you a list of its properties:

[image]

That beats trying to remember what the parameter was, six months or two years after you wrote the converter. And if the property type is an `enum`, you'll even get a list of values to pick from.

Incidentally, I would rename this converter and its parameter, to reflect the fact that what it's really doing is returning true if one integer is equal to another:

```
Converter={local:IsIntegerEqual To=400}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the ConverterParameter. Write the parameter without a apostrophe like

```
... ConverterParameter=400}"/>
```

Aditional you have to use a Convert to get the integer value like

```
int desiredZoomFactor = Convert.ToInt16(value);
```

Comment: Thanks. If I remove the apostraphe, now it tells me "the specified cast is not valid" in the output window.

Comment: Could you post a screeshot?

Comment: I have added the screen shot.

Comment: See updated question. I had to revert back to '400' and change the converter logic.

Comment: I had not realised you had edited your answer. I will give it an upvote but already accepted another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I have this bit working now.

So the converter looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace OCLMEditor.ValueConverters
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(bool))]
    public class IsCurrentZoomFactor : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int currentZoomFactor = (int)value;
            string strDesiredZoomFactor = (string)parameter;
            int desiredZoomFactor = int.Parse(strDesiredZoomFactor);
            return desiredZoomFactor == currentZoomFactor;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return int.Parse((string)parameter);
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<MenuItem x:Uid="MenuItem_12" Header="400%" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static Properties:Settings.Default}, Path=ZoomFactor, Converter={StaticResource IsCurrentZoomFactor}, ConverterParameter='400'}"/>
<MenuItem x:Uid="MenuItem_13" Header="300%" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static Properties:Settings.Default}, Path=ZoomFactor, Converter={StaticResource IsCurrentZoomFactor}, ConverterParameter='300'}"/>
<MenuItem x:Uid="MenuItem_14" Header="250%" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static Properties:Settings.Default}, Path=ZoomFactor, Converter={StaticResource IsCurrentZoomFactor}, ConverterParameter='250'}"/>
<MenuItem x:Uid="MenuItem_15" Header="200%" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static Properties:Settings.Default}, Path=ZoomFactor, Converter={StaticResource IsCurrentZoomFactor}, ConverterParameter='200'}"/>
<MenuItem x:Uid="MenuItem_16" Header="175%" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static Properties:Settings.Default}, Path=ZoomFactor, Converter={StaticResource IsCurrentZoomFactor}, ConverterParameter='175'}"/>
<MenuItem x:Uid="MenuItem_17" Header="150%" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static Properties:Settings.Default}, Path=ZoomFactor, Converter={StaticResource IsCurrentZoomFactor}, ConverterParameter='150'}"/>
<MenuItem x:Uid="MenuItem_18" Header="125%" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static Properties:Settings.Default}, Path=ZoomFactor, Converter={StaticResource IsCurrentZoomFactor}, ConverterParameter='125'}"/>
<MenuItem x:Uid="MenuItem_19" Header="100%" IsCheckable="True" InputGestureText="CTRL + 0"  IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static Properties:Settings.Default}, Path=ZoomFactor, Converter={StaticResource IsCurrentZoomFactor}, ConverterParameter='100'}">
    <MenuItem.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding x:Uid="KeyBinding_9" Key="D0"  Modifiers="Ctrl"/>
    </MenuItem.InputBindings>
</MenuItem>
<MenuItem x:Uid="MenuItem_20" Header="75%" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static Properties:Settings.Default}, Path=ZoomFactor, Converter={StaticResource IsCurrentZoomFactor}, ConverterParameter='75'}"/>
<MenuItem x:Uid="MenuItem_21" Header="50%" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static Properties:Settings.Default}, Path=ZoomFactor, Converter={StaticResource IsCurrentZoomFactor}, ConverterParameter='50'}"/>
<Separator x:Uid="Separator_8"/>
<MenuItem x:Uid="MenuItem_22" Header="Custom..."/>
```

At least now the setting is saved correctly. I know I have more work to do (like bind the click to a command).